c++でMeCabを使おうとするとコンパイル時にエラーが表示される
困ってること
文章を分解するためにMeCabを使おうとしています。
そのため、このリポジトリのライブラリフォルダを使ってC++のプログラムをコンパイルしようとしているのですが、エラーが表示されてしまいます。
https://github.com/shogo82148/mecab
コマンド
g++ test.cpp -L./dir -llibmecab -I./include -o test

エラー内容
C:/pg/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\(ユーザ名)\AppData\Local\Temp\ccmcv35O.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5MeCab12createTaggerEPKc'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

調べたこと
調べた感じだと、他にも似たようなエラーで困ってる人は見つかりましたが、回答はもらえてませんでした。
https://github.com/taku910/mecab/issues/51
コード
#include <mecab.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char input[1024] = "ジョニーは戦場へ行った";
    MeCab::Tagger *tagger = MeCab::createTagger("-Owakati");
    const char *result = tagger->parse(input);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
    std::cout << "aaaa";
}

ファイル構成


未だプログラムが作成出来ていませんね。test.cppをコンパイルした後、ライブラリとリンクして実行ファイルを作成しようとした時に、プログラム内で呼出している関数を含むライブラリがリンカー(ld.exe)のオプションに指定されていないためにエラーになっているのでしょう。こんな記事が類似の状況でしょう。MinGW 環境にて regex を使用したい！(link エラー)

mecabに関係なく、コンパイラ等のツールの使い方が分かっていないと発生するエラーです。質問文にツール構成や実行したコマンドを記載してください。

20年前の記事ですが、こんなものがありました。何か参考になるかも。MeCab ライブラリ あるいはMinGWのg++ではなくVisual Studio 2022とPythonで使おうとする際の環境構築記事がこちら。MeCab をソースコードからビルドしてインストール（形態素解析）（Windows 上）（書きかけ）

libmecab.dllとlibmecab.libはどこから入手したものでしょうか？
https://github.com/shogo82148/mecab/releases で公開されているものは、mecab-msvc-x64-0.996.10.zipとmecab-msvc-x86-0.996.10.zipというファイル名からわかるようにMSVC（Visual C++）用となります。
C言語であればMSVCとMinGWに一定の互換性はありますが、C++言語については互換性がありません。具体的にclass MeCab::Tagger* MeCab::createTagger(char const*)は

MSVC ?createTagger@MeCab@@YAPAVTagger@1@PBD@Z
G++ _ZN5MeCab12createTaggerEPKc

というように異なる名前に変換しています。このため質問のようなシンボルが見つからないというエラーになります。

Windows環境で標準のコンパイラーはVisual C++ですので、まずは標準コンパイラーを使うことをお勧めします。あえて非標準コンパイラーを選択する場合は、その旨を十二分に自覚した上で利用してください。その上で、kunifさんも触れられているようにご自身でビルドする必要があります。
なお、vcpkgというパッケージマネージャがMeCabにも対応しているため、環境を整えていれば
vcpkg install mecab

で導入できます。

どうしてもGCCでコンパイルしたいというのであれば、MSYS2のMinGW-w64版GCCを使うことをお勧めします。MSYS2であればmecabのバイナリパッケージも用意されてますので、自分でmecabをコンパイルする必要もありません。
下記はx64環境でMSYS2のGCCでコンパイルする手順です。

MSYS2をインストールする。
"ucrt64.exe"を実行して、UCRT64のMSYS2を立ち上げる。(以下の作業は、すべてこのUCRT64のMSYS2環境で実施してください。コマンドプロンプトやPowerShellで実行してもうまくいきません。)
pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-toolchain でコンパイル環境一式を入れる。(コンパイラだけが必要であれば、gccだけでも良いかもしれない。)
pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-mecab でmecabを入れる。
g++ test.cpp -lmecab -o test でコンパイルする。
コンパイル出来たら、./testで実行してみる。

-lで指定は"mecab"のみです。実際のdllにはlibがついていますが、Linux等と同様、リンク時に指定するときはいりません。
なお、UCRT64のMSYS2以外の環境で実行するときは、libmecab-2.dll含めたいくつかのDLLが必要なります。lddでOS標準以外のDLLを確認して、exeと同じディレクトリにコピーしておいてください。
ついでに、私の環境ではコンパイル自体は成功しますが、実行するとSegmentation faultになりました。コードが悪いのか、MinGW-w64版GCC特有の問題なのかまでは、調べていません。
